# Left adjoint to inclusion of Connected Groupoids into Groupoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, groupoids, adjoint-functors

Let $Gpd$ denote the category of groupoids and functors. Let $Gpd_{con}$ denote the subcategory spanned by connected groupoids, i.e for every $x,y\in Ob(Gpd_{con})$, there is at least one morphism $x\rightarrow y$.

Does the canonical inclusion $i:Gpd_{con}\rightarrow Gpd$ have a left adjoint? If so, does it preserve products?

Comment: Do you mean the 1-categories of groupoids and connected groupoids, or the 2-categories thereof?

Comment: @MikeShulman The 1-categories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not.  If it did, then $\mathrm{Gpd}_{\mathrm{con}}$, like any reflective subcategory, would be closed under limits in $\mathrm{Gpd}$.  But it is not closed under equalizers.  For instance, let $X$ be the contractible groupoid with two objects $x,y$, and $G$ any nontrivial group regarded as a connected groupoid, let $f:X\to G$ send the isomorphism $x\cong y$ to the identity of $G$, and let $g:X\to G$ send it to some nonidentity element of $G$.  Then the equalizer of $f$ and $g$ in $\mathrm{Gpd}$ is the discrete groupoid on two objects, which is no longer connected.